# how to block http request until callback method called

Tags: http-request

Are there any idears to block http request until callback method called?
like this(if use java):

```
protected void get(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
{
    dosomething();

    // call some async service
    call_some_service(new Callback(){
        public void callback(String result)
        {
            // continue request
            request.continue();
        }
    });

    // wait for callback 
    request.wait();
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CountDownLatch with a count of 1.